# How to build a Python C Extension so I can import it from a module

Tags: python, distutils, python-extensions

I have a Python project with many sub-modules that I package up with distutils.  I would like to build some Python extensions in C to live in some of these sub-modules but I don't understand how to get the Python extension to live in a submodule.  What follows is the simplest example of what I'm looking for:

Here is my Python extension `c_extension.c`:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
get_answer(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("i", 42);
}

static PyMethodDef Methods[] = {
    {"get_answer",  get_answer, METH_VARARGS, "The meaning of life."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initc_extension(void) {
  (void) Py_InitModule("c_extension", Methods);
}
```

And here is a `setup.py` that works:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(name='c_extension_demo',
      ext_modules = [Extension('c_extension', sources = ['c_extension.c'])])
```

After installing in an virtualenv I can do this:

```
>>> import c_extension
>>> c_extension.get_answer()
42
```

But I would like to have `c_extension` live in a sub-module, say `foo.bar`.  What do I need to change in this pipeline to be able to get the behavior in the Python shell to be like this:

```
>>> import foo.bar.c_extension
>>> foo.bar.c_extension.get_answer()
42
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12097755/7954504

Comment: For `python >= 3.10` , `distutils` is deprecated, please see [my answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67759085/9853105) for detail

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just change

```
Extension('c_extension', ...)
```

to

```
Extension('foo.bar.c_extension', ...)
```

You will need `__init__.py` files in each of the `foo` and `bar` directories, as usual. To have these packaged with the module in your setup.py, you need to add

```
packages = ['foo', 'foo.bar'],
```

to your setup() call, and you will need the directory structure

```
setup.py
foo/
    __init__.py
    bar/
        __init__.py
```

in your source directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that didn't work for me.  I made `foo/bar` directory with an `__init__.py` in each plus added the `foo.bar.` prefix in the setup command but in the python shell this happens:

    >>> import foo.bar.c_extension
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named c_extension

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I'm testing on 2.7.3.

Comment: Don't test from your source directory. That will try to import from the foo/bar in the source dir which doesn't have c_extension.

Comment: Oh RIGHT.  That was it.  Thank you for the help!