# How to put my Python C-module inside package?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-module, distutils

I would like to gather multiple Python modules under one package, so they do not reserve too many names from global set of python packages and modules. But I have problems with modules that are written in C.

Here is a very simple example, straight from the official Python documentation. You can find it at the bottom of the page from here: http://docs.python.org/distutils/examples.html

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
setup(name='foobar',
      version='1.0',
      ext_modules=[Extension('foopkg.foo', ['foo.c'])],
      )
```

My foo.c file looks like this

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
foo_bar(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);

static PyMethodDef FooMethods[] = {
    {
        "bar",
        foo_bar,
        METH_VARARGS,
        ""
    },
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static PyObject *
foo_bar(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("s", "foobar");
}

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initfoo(void)
{
    (void)Py_InitModule("foo", FooMethods);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Pass argv[0] to the Python interpreter
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);

    // Initialize the Python interpreter.  Required.
    Py_Initialize();

    // Add a static module
    initfoo();

    return 0;
}
```

It builds and installs fine, but I cannot import foopkg.foo! If I rename it to just "foo" it works perfectly.

Any ideas how I can make the "foopkg.foo" work? For example changing "foo" from Py_InitModule() in C code to "foopkg.foo" does not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There must be an `__init__.py` file in the `foopkg` folder, otherwise Python does not recognize as a package.

Create a `foopkg` folder where `setup.py` is, and put an empty file `__init__.py` there, and add a `packages` line to `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
setup(name='foobar',
      version='1.0',
      packages=['foopkg'],
      ext_modules=[Extension('foopkg.foo', ['foo.c'])],
      )
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks :)

Although I still think that should have been mentioned in the Python docs :/

Answer (score 1):

[`distutils` will be deprecated since python 3.10](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0632/) , instead you can use [`setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is an enhanced alternative of `distutils` , so you don't need to pass `packages` argument in your `setup()`. For example :

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
setup(name='foobar',
      version='1.0',
      ext_modules=[Extension('foopkg.foo', ['foo.c'])],
      )
```

Then build and install your C extension

```
python /PATH/TO/setup.py install
```

After building your C extension successfully, test whether it can be imported as expected by running this command:

```
python -c "from foopkg import foo"
```

[side note]
One more thing about `setuptool` is that you can uninstall the C extension package by simply running `pip uninstall`, for example : `python -m pip uninstall foobar`