# Trouble importing extension compiled with numpy.distutils

Tags: python, numpy, distutils, f2py, python-extensions

I have a project directory structure:

```
myproject/
  setup.py
  myproject/
     editors/
       ....
     utilities/
       ...
       find_inf.f90
```

All the files in the project are python, except for the one fortran file that i have indicated. Now, I can use `setuptools` to install my project without the fortran file just fine, but to include the fortran file i have to use `numpy.distutils.core.Extension`. So I have a setup files like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension

ext1 = Extension(name = 'myproject.find_inf',
                 sources = ['myproject/utilities/find_inf.f90'], 
                 extra_f90_compile_args=['-fopenmp',],
                 libraries=['gomp'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(name = 'myproject',
          packages=find_packages(),
          package_data={
              ......
          },
          entry_points={
              'console_scripts': [....]
          },

          ext_modules = [ext1]
          )
```

This creates and installs `myproject-2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg` under the `site-packages` directory and the directory structure looks like:

```
myproject-2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg
      myproject
          editors\  
          find_inf.pyc
          find_inf.so.dSYM/  
          find_inf.py   
          find_inf.so*
          __init__.py  
          __init__.pyc
```

So it looks to me that I should be able to import `find_inf` from `myproject`. But i can't! Writing `from myproject import find_inf` produces an import error. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

If I chance the name of the extension from `my project.find_inf` to just `find_inf` then the installation puts the extension directly in `myproject-2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg`. If then I **manually move** the find_inf files from there to `myproject-2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/myproject` then I can import the extension. I still can't make sense of this. Something is clearly wrong in my setup.py that it is not putting the extension in the right place....

**UPDATE:**
Figured it out. Answer below.

Comment: Can you show the traceback.

Comment: The traceback is quite terse, it's just:
``ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0d00ebc2a245> in <module>()
----> 1 from myproject import find_inf

ImportError: cannot import name find_inf``

Comment: Are sure `find_inf.f90` is really in  `myproject` and not in a sub directory?

Comment: No, the relative source location is ``myproject/utilities/find_inf.f90`` as is used in the constructor to ``Extension``.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out. The `name=` argument to `Extension` should have been `name=myproject.utilities.find_inf`.

**Reason:** So the issue is that there is no package named `myproject.find_inf` that `setup()` is aware of. The `packages=` argument to setup gets the names of the packages (as a list) and `myproject.find_inf` wasn't in the list because there is no directory under myproject called find_inf (as the directory structure in my question shows). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097755/how-to-build-a-python-c-extension-so-i-can-import-it-from-a-module) sheds important light on this issue. In order to have the compiled extensions placed under an appropriate sub-package, one needs:

1. those sub-packages to be present in the source directory structure
2. `__init__.py` files should exist in those packages, and
3. the names of those package have to be passed to the `packages=` argument in `setup()`.

i.e. simply describing the extension hierarchy in the call to `Extension()` is not enough.