# How to package a Python C Extension such that it is a submodule of a normal Python module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I wrote a python library with two parts:

1. A Python C extension
2. A Python wrapper for the Python C extension

I would like to be able to package it in such a way that the Python wrapper is the top level module `foo` and the Python C extension is a submodule located at `foo._foo`. However I have so far only been able to create two top level modules, `foo` and `_foo`.

What do I need to do in `setup.py` and in the `init_foo` C function in order to accomplish this?

(My question is subtlety different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097755/how-to-build-a-python-c-extension-so-i-can-import-it-from-a-module))

---

Current directory structure:

```
foo/
    foo/
        __init__.py
    foo.c
    setup.py
    tests.py
```

`setup.py` looks something like:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module = Extension('_foo',
                   sources=['foo.c'])

setup(name='foo', packages=['foo'], ext_modules=[module])
```

`foo.c` looks something like:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC init_foo(void) {
    PyObject *m;
    m = Py_InitModule("_foo", FooMethods);
    // ..
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0])
    Py_Initialize();
    init_pychbase();
}
```

`foo/__init__.py` looks something like:

```
from _foo import _Foo, _Bar, _Baz

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = _Foo()
```

Comment: @MatthewMoisen You said "(My question is subtlety different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097755/how-to-build-a-python-c-extension-so-i-can-import-it-from-a-module))" could you explain why?

Comment: @MSeifert after taking another go at it, I now realize it wasn't different enough to warrant a new question. (The difference is that I want my c extension one level deep, whereas the OP wanted his two levels deep). My issue was that my `tests.py` file was located in the same directory as the foo module so the imports were off when I ran it. Creating a `tests/tests.py` setup solved this.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the linked question, the solution is simply to change `_foo` to `foo._foo`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module = Extension('foo._foo',
                   sources=['foo.c'])

setup(name='foo', packages=['foo'], ext_modules=[module])
```

My issue was that I was running my `tests.py` from the same directory as the `foo` module was located in.

I fixed this by bringing it into its own directory:

```
/foo
    /foo
        __init__.py
    foo.c
    setup.py
    /tests
         test.py
```