# Building Python submodules from C++ extensions via cmake

Tags: python, c++, cmake, module, setuptools

I'm trying to incorporate a c++ extension as a submodule into an existing python library via cmake. Building the C++ extension works fine and importing it as a python module works, but not as the submodule of the header library.

I have the following directory structure:

```
frontend/
   foo.py
   bar.py
   backend/
      backend.cpp
```

The extension is bound to a python module via pybind:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(backend, m)
{
    m.doc() = "backend c++ implementation"; // optional module docstring
    m.def("method", &method, "The method I want to call from python.");
}
```

In the CMakeLists.txt, the relevant line is:

```
pybind11_add_module(backend "frontend/backend/backend.cpp")
```

I've followed the instructions form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048421/how-to-package-a-python-c-extension-such-that-it-is-a-submodule-of-a-normal-pyth) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585210/extending-setuptools-extension-to-use-cmake-in-setup-py) to write the setup.py script. I guess the most important lines look like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext
from setuptools.command.test import test as TestCommand

class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, name, sourcedir=".", sources=[]):
        Extension.__init__(self, name, sources=[])


class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    def run(self):
        build_directory = os.path.abspath(self.build_temp)
        if not os.path.exists(self.build_temp):
            os.makedirs(self.build_temp)

        cmake_list_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        print("-" * 10, "Running CMake prepare", "-" * 40)
        subprocess.check_call(
            ["cmake", cmake_list_dir], cwd=self.build_temp,
        )

        print("-" * 10, "Building extensions", "-" * 40)
        cmake_cmd = ["cmake", "--build", "."] + self.build_args
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_cmd, cwd=self.build_temp)

        # Move from build temp to final position
        for ext in self.extensions:
            self.move_output(ext)

    def move_output(self, ext):
        build_temp = Path(self.build_temp).resolve()
        dest_path = Path(self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name)).resolve()
        source_path = build_temp / self.get_ext_filename(ext.name)
        dest_directory = dest_path.parents[0]
        dest_directory.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        self.copy_file(source_path, dest_path)


extensions = [CMakeExtension("backend")]

setup(
    name="frontend",
    packages=["frontend"],
    ext_modules=extensions,
    cmdclass=dict(build_ext=CMakeBuild),
)
```

But this does not make `backend` a submodule of `frontend`, but instead a module on its own. So this works:

```
from backend import method
```

But to avoid naming issues with other libraries, what I would like to have is this:

```
from frontend.backend import method
```

Changing the naming in the pybinding or in the extension call to `extensions = [CMakeExtension("frontend.backend")]` does unfortunately not resolve my problem, the setup does not find the `backend.<platform>.so` shared library then, because it looks for `frontend/backend.<platform>.so`, which does not exist. How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: `CMakeExtension("frontend.backend")]` should be correct. How are you running setup.py?

Comment: By ```pip install .```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've resolved the issue with the following lines:

Change in the setup.py file:

```
ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "frontend.backend", sources=["frontend/backend/backend.cpp"]
    )
]
```

Change in the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
pybind11_add_module(backend "frontend/backend/backend.cpp")
set_target_properties( backend
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/frontend"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/frontend"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/frontend"
)
```

The shared library object backend.platform.so must be located in the frontend directory. Neither the pybind module name nor the sourcefile .cpp should contain any "." in the names, because the `get_ext_fullpath()` method from `build_ext` will split by dots. Only the frontend directory containts an **init**.py file.