# Python C-extension submodule Error: no module named "x"

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-c-api

I'm having difficulty with making a C-extension as a submodule in my code. The C extension below compiles just fine. The problem occurs when I attempt to add it to another module.

Here's the C code: The file name is prctl3-0.c. I am able to get it compiling for both Python2.7 and Python 3.0.

```c
#include <Python.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>

// Now we need to identify which version of Python we are working with.
//  For backwards compatibility, we need to be able to be compiled by either
//  Python 2.7 or Python3.x.

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >=3
#define PY_3CODE            // We will use this pre-compile statement to differentiate
                            //  between code for Py2.7 and 3.x
#endif

/* osCall_changeName
  Calls prctl() to change the name of the calling thread, process or subprocess

*/
static PyObject* osCall_changeName(PyObject*self, PyObject* args)
{
  const char *passedInName;   // Name passed in by the system
  size_t nameLength;          // Calculated by calling strlen() on passedInName

  char newName[16];           // In Python newName= passedInName[0:15]+ \0
  int nameChangeRes;          // stores error code for calling prctl()

  PyObject *retName;          // Return value; Python None if error occurs

  // Check if argument passed in successfully
  if(! PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &passedInName)){
    printf("Error in arg passing\n");
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
  }

  nameLength = strlen(passedInName);
  if( nameLength > 15){       // prctl() automatically truncates, but unsure if new string is null-terminated
     strncpy(newName, passedInName, 15);
     newName[15] = '\0';
  } else {
    strcpy(newName, passedInName);
  }

  //Actual function call
  nameChangeRes = prctl(PR_SET_NAME, newName, 0,0,0);

  if( nameChangeRes == 0 )    // Success; pass back the changed name value
  {
    retName = Py_BuildValue("s", newName);
    return retName;
  }

  // Method failed; return None
  Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyObject* osCall_getName(PyObject* self) {

  char procName[16];          // Buffer to put prctl results into
  int  nameRetrieveRes;       // Result of the name retrieval operation
  PyObject *retName;          // Python object to return values


  nameRetrieveRes = prctl(PR_GET_NAME, procName, 0,0,0);

  if ( nameRetrieveRes == 0 ) //
  {
      retName = Py_BuildValue("s", procName);
      return retName;
  }
  printf("Process name change failed\n");
  // Operation failed; return None
  Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

//==========================================================
//  STEP 2: COMPILE THE PIECES NEEDED FOR EITHER 2.7 OR 3.X
//    PYTHON LIBRARIES
//==========================================================

static PyMethodDef proc_OsFunc[] = {
  { "changeName",
  (PyCFunction)osCall_changeName,
  METH_VARARGS,
  "Function to give Python process a new associated string ID"},

  { "getName",
  (PyCFunction)osCall_getName,
  METH_NOARGS,
  "Function to get Python process's current string ID"
  },

  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL} //function array terminator
};

#ifdef PY_3CODE
static struct PyModuleDef osCallDefine = {
  PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
  "prctl3_0",
  "A simple library for accessing prctl() on Linux from Python 3.0",
  -1,
  proc_OsFunc
};

#endif

#ifdef PY_3CODE
// Python 3.0 initialization syntax
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_prctl3_0(void)
{
  Py_Initialize();

  return PyModule_Create(&osCallDefine);
}

#else
// Python 2.0 initialization syntax
PyMODINIT_FUNC initprctl3_0() {
  Py_InitModule3("prctl3_0",proc_OsFunc,
        "A simple library for accessing prctl() on Linux from Python 2.0");
}



#endif
```

I hope to have this code in a module name `mpIPC` as part of a larger project. The problem I'm having is when I put it into a larger module, and try to access it using the following code, I get the following:

```
>>> import mpIPC.prctl3_0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named prctl3_0
```

My `setup.py` file is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension

prctl_module = Extension("mpIPC.prctl3_0",
                                sources = ["mpIPC/prctl3_0.c"])

setup(name = "mpIPC",
    version = '0.0',
    description = "Python C module for accessing Linux commands for IPC",
    packages = ['mpIPC'],
    ext_modules = [prctl_module] )
```

My file directory for this module:

```
project/
+- setup.py
+- mkdir/
-+- __init__.py 
-+- prctl3_0.c
-+- os.py   # used for other Linux os calls
```

I'm not really sure what I am missing. I have also checked the following link:
[How to build a Python C Extension so I can import it from a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097755/how-to-build-a-python-c-extension-so-i-can-import-it-from-a-module)
but it's not really helping me at this point.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, definitely do not make a module named `os.py` because it has the potential to shadow the standard library's `os` module (especially on Python 2) and that will confuse you and others.

Comment: Good point. Will make a note to our manager to change the module name to something less conflict-prone.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can *generally* avoid problems like this by including `from __future__ import absolute_import` (which actually you're probably already doing, else you're very lucky things aren't breaking :)  But it's still better not to use the names of Python stdlib modules in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working without any source-modifications.

1. Your directory "mkdir" **must** be named "mpIPC", which is the module name. You'll want your directory structure to look like at the bottom
2. do **not** attempt to test this from within your source-directory, i.e. not from anywhere in `project`, as that will attempt to import, according to Python's module structure, from the directory "mpIPC" (which you will have created in 1)) (credit for this hint goes to [this comment in the post you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097755/how-to-build-a-python-c-extension-so-i-can-import-it-from-a-module#comment16168027_12097916). Instead, try it from anywhere in your home-dir, for example. That is, supposing you ran `python setup.py install` first :)

Directory tree:

```
foobar
    ├── mpIPC
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── os.py
    │   └── prctl3_0.c
    └── setup.py
```

Comment: If you want to test an extension module from within the source tree run `./setup.py build_ext --inplace`.  This places the built shared module into the source code.  That is, the build process will copy `prctl3_0.so` into the `mpIPC` directory alongside the source code.  Then, from the top of the source tree you can run `import mpIPC.prctl3_0` and it will work.  I generally find this more convenient for development, but others have other opinions (either way make sure not to commit this to source control!).

Comment: @Iguananut, I have similar problems as OP, however, for some reason, my extension works as a standalone module or if I import from outside the project directory, the functions of the extension are exposed at the top-module and they are an older version. The answer above doesn't seem to work for me, but your suggestion with the --inplace flag is the only thing sofar that works properly. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? Any help is much appreciated